# Azure pipeline secret variable in library to set environment variables on build agent

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have in AzureDevops secret in Library called secretabc wit value.
Then I got pipeline and I want to content/text of this secret save in another file but not as ****(asterisk) only I want text of secret.
How to do that?. I red a documentation but no idea.
If I use echo $(secretabc) > file, in file are only ***(asterisk)
give me a small code for that to test.

Answer (score 0):

I have this pipeline

```
stages:
- stage: DUMP
  jobs:
  - job: Dump
    displayName: Dump
    variables:
    - group: SomeVariable
    steps:
    - bash: |
        pwd
        echo "$(SomeSecret)" >> dump.txt
```

and it works. In pipeline I have real secret not `***`. But if I run from the pipeline `cat dump.txt` than I see `***`. This is prevention to expose secret in the logs. So all texts which matches secret value would be masked.

But if you publish this file as an artifact and download it you will see real value.